# Assigning an integer in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on making a tile-based game in Java. When the player clicks on a tile with a monster on it while an item is equipped, a window opens (handled by a class). This window gives the character three buttons so they can choose which part of the monster they want to attack. When they click a button, this makes a class run to handle that attack.

The problem I'm having is in assigning an Integer that the Window.class can apply. The window code has Zapper.shootHigh(); to run shootHigh from class Zapper. From Window.class with only shootHigh() I get this error: shootHigh (Integer) in Zapper cannot be applied to ().

Okay, no big deal, right? I've been working on making any kind of parameter that the Zapper class can apply in the () space. I've been unable to come up with anything. I've tried various assignments, but I can't figure out how to make a cell return an Integer. I know I could just make it Zapper.shootHigh(1) and always shoot at tile 1, but that's not much of an option.

Here's the Zapper.class code:

```
public static void shootHigh(Integer target) {

        if (target != null) {

            if (target == curUser.pos) {
                GLog.i( TXT_SELF_TARGET );
                return;
            }

            final Wand curWand = (Wand)Wand.curItem;

            curWand.setKnown();

            final int cell = Ballistica.cast( curUser.pos, target,true,     curWand.hitChars );
            curUser.sprite.zap( cell );

            QuickSlot.target( curItem, Actor.findChar( cell ) );

             if (curWand.curCharges > 0) {

            curUser.busy();

            curWand.fx(cell, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    curWand.onZap(cell);
                    curWand.wandUsed();
                }
            });

            Invisibility.dispel();

        } else {

                curUser.spendAndNext( TIME_TO_ZAP );
                GLog.w( TXT_FIZZLES );
                curWand.levelKnown = true;

                curWand.updateQuickslot();
            }

        }
```

So the target is at the cell specified, and the wand zaps that particular cell if the wand has enough charges.

I guess what I'm asking is, how can I create another Integer in Zapper.class that will tell Zapper.shootHigh() which cell number it should be shooting at?

Is there any way to initialize a variable here so an Integer will be recognized as the value of 'cell'? Or better yet, 'target'?

I think I may also be not understanding how I can declare the Integer variable target. Is there another way I can declare target as an Integer and initialize it without making it an argument in the format (Integer target)?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking. Could you elaborate your intentions and also post some more code, e.g. the code calling `shootHigh`?

Comment: I added all the shootHigh code. I'm unfortunately not sure that I can elaborate more on my intentions. How might I clarify what I'm asking? I'd love to get as much help as possible on this, so I'd like to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but i maybe wrong.

Why don't u create a 'public Interger getTarget()' method in zapper class, then give a reference of zapper class to window class, then from window class inside shootHigh method u can call getTarget() method.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm definitely going to give this a try. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for- I'm still getting used to working around problems like the one I'm having.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks again, sir.